# apt-get update stopped working

Tags: kali-linux

I was trying to solve an issue of not having enough space in my Kali Linux
and at one point I entered the command:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
```

I deleted everything in the lists directory and now when I type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the following error:

```
Err:1 https://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 104.18.244.114 443]

Reading package lists... Done

Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 104.18.244.114 443]
```

Here is the output of my df -h

Filesystem      Size      Used     Avail     Use%     Mounted on

udev            7.8G       64M      7.8G       1%     /dev

tmpfs           1.6G      159M      1.5G      10%     /run

/dev/sda1       213G  213G     0 100% /

tmpfs           7.9G   30M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm

tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock

tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

tmpfs           1.6G   12K  1.6G   1% /run/user/133

tmpfs           1.6G   52K  1.6G   1% /run/user/0

tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /media/directory

How can i allocated memory from other partitions to the root partition?

Comment: Can i add space from other paritions in the system?

Comment: @JeffSchaller i edited the question to show the setup.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the error output:

> 28: No space left on device

your disk is still full. You need to free up more space, preferably not by deleting files which the system needs. You could delete the contents of `/var/cache`, those files will be replaced as needed.

Deleting `/var/lib/apt/lists` isn’t fatal, `apt-get update` will download the files which were in that directory again, if there’s enough room for them.

Comment: It looks like my root directory is full can i move space from other parts of the system to root ?